# Granting full global domain admin rights to license reseller?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing, administrative-privileges

We are buying Microsoft 365 licenses and the reseller is requesting full global domain admin rights in order to administer the licenses.

I'm thinking, "no way in Hello Kitty", but maybe I'm being unrealistic.

Is this a normal request? Is there a better permission set to provide them? What's the typical expectation here?

I'm thinking [global reader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide), if anything, but I'm still in the camp that the reseller should not get visibility at all into our domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, only [Billing Administrator privilege](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide) is required for a reseller to manage licenses within your tenancy.

Answer (score 1):

No, I work for a reseller and our shop never asked such, but our customers just order more license when they need more, or less.

Are you sure the shop you asked are a reseller ? as some small IT business would add the license via the customer portal directly to manage the licensing. It’s simplier for the tech but it bypass the reseller quote.

A but, we do manage 0365 for some customers to help them setup/start it, in such time we need access, but it’s another question as it can be a consultant at that point or any other IT ressources.

If you dont thrust your reseller to manage your 0365, just ask someone else to manage it, but as you talk read only access I guess the term administers dont mean the same thing for them as for you.

Comment: We aren't asking for their support, and they are a big reseller with their own fancy "online portal" through which we (?) can manage our licenses.

Comment: I totally get that if the reseller is also supporting, you need admin rights. But we've been clear that we just want the dang licenses... And they are not giving us an option for any other kind of access.

Comment: @schroeder Its strange if you already stated you only want the licence.. I would use another reseller honestly, as I confirm the reseller dont need ay access, it just need your org name/ email used for 0365 to sell you the license to be added to your portal.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a normal request?

This is a terrible idea.

Microsoft is good at providing a way for organizations to shoot their foot off in O365.  The US Cybersecurity and Infrastructure Security Agency (CISA) found last year that many third party vendors that performed these types of integrations did exactly that.

https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/analysis-reports/AR19-133A

Comment: I'm with you on the "terrible idea" part. I don't need convincing of that. But is it normal? What should I propose as an alternate course of action?